# SELECT with INNER JOIN, GROUP BY and LIMIT

Tags: mysql

I have a three tables about movies. First one is `movie`, second one is `actor` and last one is `movie_actor_mapping`. I wrote an query that select data from table movie and group actors for each movie. And my query select all actors from `actor` table but I have to select only first 4 actors. How can I modify my select to do it?

```
SELECT title, year, poster, rating, group_concat(a.name separator ', ') as actors
FROM movie m
INNER JOIN movie_actor_mapping ma ON m.movie_id = ma.movie_id
INNER JOIN actor a ON a.actor_id = ma.actor_id
WHERE m.rating IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY m.movie_id
ORDER BY m.rating DESC;
```

Comment: First 4 in what order? Alphabetical?

Comment: Hi! Just first in table

Comment: Tables don't have any ordering, you have to use `ORDER BY` to specify the order in a query.

Comment: Anyway, see See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2129693/mysql-using-limit-within-group-by-to-get-n-results-per-group for how to  for how to get 4 actors per movie. Join that with the movie table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can hack it around by `substringing` `group_concat` output to first 3 results, e.g.:

```
select m.name as movie, substring_index(group_concat(a.name SEPARATOR ','), ',', 3) as actors
from movie m
join movie_actor ma on m.id = ma.movie_id
join actor a on ma.actor_id = a.id
group by m.id
order by m.id, a.id;
```

This would give you 3 actors per movie.

Here is the [**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/5dd391/16/0).

Comment: Thank you so much!